Amazon product advertising api - how to get lightning offers?
I am developing an Amazon Bot to scrape the best deals from Amazon. I am using the Amazon PA API to search for products with the following code:
search_items_resource = [
    SearchItemsResource.ITEMINFO_TITLE,
    SearchItemsResource.OFFERS_LISTINGS_PROMOTIONS,
    SearchItemsResource.OFFERS_LISTINGS_PRICE,
    SearchItemsResource.IMAGES_PRIMARY_LARGE,
    SearchItemsResource.OFFERS_LISTINGS_SAVINGBASIS,
    SearchItemsResource.OFFERS_SUMMARIES_HIGHESTPRICE,
    SearchItemsResource.OFFERS_SUMMARIES_LOWESTPRICE,
    SearchItemsResource.PARENTASIN,
]

# Forming request
try:
    search_items_request = SearchItemsRequest(
        partner_tag=PARTNER_TAG,
        partner_type=PartnerType.ASSOCIATES,
        keywords=KEYWORDS,
        search_index=SEARCH_INDEX,
        min_reviews_rating=MIN_REVIEWS_RATING,
        item_count=ITEM_COUNT,
        resources=search_items_resource,
        availability="Available"
    )
except ValueError as exception:
    print("Error in forming SearchItemsRequest: ", exception)
    return

My problem is that I can't find a solution for scanning the deals page on Amazon (https://www.amazon.de/gp/angebote). Is there any possible way to do this using the API or any other method?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried different keywords such as "deals," but I'm unable to find the exact same products as those on the Deals page.
